# Unable to push view controller when I use UISearchController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have `UISearchcontroller`. When I select a searched item and try to push a `viewcontroller`, the `viewcontroller` is not being pushed. The reason for this issue is when I set `self.definespresentationcontext` to `NO`. Its working if I set the `self.definespresentationcontext` to `YES`, but the searchbar beomes hidden.

Example :

```
    self.searchResultController = [[MyResultsController alloc]init];
    self.searchResultController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.searchResultController];
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
    self.searchController.searchBar.translucent = YES;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    self.definesPresentationContext = NO;
```

Can somebody help me out to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please post some code? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
presentingViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(eventDetailsViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: you are super hero

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your UIViewController is set to render under Top Bars and then everything should work as expected.

> self.definesPresentationContext = YES

[image: Interface Builder]

Comment: This will bring down the search bar below the navigation bar.